# SQLite static openDatabase database method error in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, opendatabase

I created a static method to access my database on one of my activities but I keep getting error on opening the database.

MainActivity

```
 public static String getStudentData() {

    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  null;

    try {
            //NOT WORKING
        sampleDB =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("studentDB",null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
            //Also not working
        //sampleDB =  SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("studentDB", null);

        Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student where id='1'", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //...                       
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception se ) {
    } finally {
            sampleDB.close();
    }
}
```

OtherActivity

```
String student = MainActivity.getStudentData();
```

I have been getting `sqlite3_open_v2("studentDB", &handle, 6, NULL) failed`. Cant find what's wrong... I have also tried using `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. Currently using `MODE_PRIVATE`for database creation. Please help me out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First argument to `openDatabase` should be full path to db so if:

```
//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "studentDB";
```

then you should call:

```
sampleDB =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
```

Comment: wow, you are right! I didnt expect I need to input the full path for static method. Usually, I will just do `sampleDB =  SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("studentDB", null);` within the activity. First time trying out static methods. Thanks!

Comment: don't we have to put the extension "studentDB.db" or "studentDB.sqlite" ?

Comment: Adding SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY is what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use a method [ContextWrapper#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) and pass the result to `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase`:

```
File dbFile= myActivity.getDatabasePath("studentDB");
sampleDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
```